# PostgreSQL Create Trigger which runs a function on every insert or update of a table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have defined two tables, `scores` and `analyzed_avg_score`, in my postgres database. I also have a function which i declaired like that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION updateAvgScore() RETURNS void AS $$
    INSERT into analyzed_avg_score
        (SELECT 
            user,
            avg(score_value)
        FROM
            scores
        group by user) on conflict do nothing;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Now, I want to have a trigger or something similar that runs this function every time I insert or update something in `score`. I don't have a lot of experience with SQL, yet. So, does anyone have an idea how the trigger should look like?

Comment: While you can do this with a trigger, it would be much simpler to just create a view that shows the average per user.  If you do end up using a trigger, don't forget about running it on deletes as well and modifying your current function to update `analyzed_avg_score` when the user already exists instead of doing nothing.

Comment: didn't thought about creating a view. That's definitly the better way, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER SCORE_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON SCORE
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE updateAvgScore();


/*Have it return a trigger like this */

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updateAvgScore() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $example_table$
   BEGIN
      /*YOUR lOGIC HERE*/
   END;
$example_table$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I get the following error when I execute it:
```ERROR: function updateavgscore must return type trigger```

Comment: Updated please check now